# Modules & services 404 error - Prestashop

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, prestashop

When i click on `Modules & Services` tab on back office it redirect to 404 error page.
Url is like below

`https://example.com/admin301f2qz0v/index.php/module/catalog?_token=rwsJaBnDlZ5O28QVeFYLeA4P2D--ySMEhhqLOcsJxA0`

I tried

- Re generating .htaccess file
- Replaced nginx.conf file as like below

https://github.com/MattLoyeD/Prestashop-Nginx/blob/master/prestashop-nginx.conf

but still got 404 error.

Prestashop version : 1.7.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Regenerating the .htaccess file won't have any effect if you are using NGINX. Add these lines to your configuration if they are not there (replace admin-dev by your admin directory name:

```
location /admin-dev{
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/.*$ /admin-dev/index.php last;
    }
}
```

The admin panel has several pages that are accessed in a different way. That snipped will chage the way the page is accessed in some of the cases.